Running virtual environment created by poetry inside Docker container
I need to install my application using poetry and then run it after activating the virtual environment created by it, this is my Dockerfile
FROM ghcr.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.9.0

RUN apt clean
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y pipx python3-pip libhdf5-dev pkg-config

RUN pipx install poetry
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir "/root/enrichment-consumer"
COPY . "/root/enrichment-consumer"
WORKDIR "/root/enrichment-consumer"

RUN poetry source add --priority=supplemental leitha-internal-py http://***:***@nexus-leitha.servizi.gr-u.it/repository/leitha-internal-py/simple
RUN poetry config certificates.leitha-internal-py.cert false
RUN poetry install

RUN export VENV_PATH=$(poetry env info --path)

CMD ${VENV_PATH}/bin/python enrichment_consumer/app.py

The problem is that using poetry shell before running the python command will spawn an interactive shell thus blocking the container run whereas trying to activate the virtual environment like above I get the following error:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "$VENV_PATH/bin/python": stat $VENV_PATH/bin/python: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled


Integrating Python Poetry with Docker has several examples; does one of those setups work?  This answer suggests RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false, which will have Poetry install packages into the "system" Python, but in Docker that's still isolated in an image, and you avoid the complexity of needing to set up a virtual environment.

@DavidMaze disabling the virtual environment creation won't complete the package installation process as it raise a EnvCommandError error: externally-managed-environment
